# pandas json normalize get values in object index

Tags: python, json, pandas

Inside of `fuelUse.urban` and `fuelUse.road` I have an array of objects.

```
fuelUse:Object
  urban:Array
    0:Object
    1:Object
      value:10.5
      unit:"km/l"
      type:"gasolina"
```

How can I normalize the JSON to get the values from index 1 in dataframe? I tried this but have key error:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(cars)[['name','price.value','configuration','dimensions.trunkVolume.value','fuelUse.urban.1.value','fuelUse.road.1.value']]
```

Comment: Please show your code and the error.

Comment: add the json that is contents of `cars` to the post.  I've navigated around embedded arrays and bugs with pandas for this.  `json.dumps(cars, indent=2)` will be useful